# How to make a blur effect like the background like 3D touch

Tags: ios, blur, uivisualeffectview

I need make a blur effect of my custom view, and just look like the same with 3D touch.

PS: I didn't find the UIVisualEffectView support this effect.Our system only support three UIBlurEffectStyle,which are not the same with 3D touch.

this image is about 3D touch peek pop background :
[image]

and this is UIVisualEffectView of UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight style:
[image]

THX in advance

Answer (score -1):

Please add following code for backgroundView of customView...

```
 UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];// you have a list of options for UIBlurEffectStyle
 UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
 blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds; // Make your own frame
 blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; // Skip this line if you are using new style of coding
 [bgImageV addSubview:blurEffectView];
```

Comment: but ,I guess this style `UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight ` is not the same with 3D touch.. (the blur radius looks like not the same)

Comment: @boog can you please share some image or something like that, what you really want.

Comment: image is here now